# mysql_real_escape_string is not working properly for get method

Tags: php

Code works on localhost but not live server

Here is my code

```
if(isset($_GET['email'])){
  $email   = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['email']);
}
else{
  $email   = '';
}
if(isset($_GET['mobile'])){
  $mobile   = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['mobile']);
else{
  $mobile   = '';
}
echo "Email : ".$email;
echo "<br>";
echo "Mobile : ".$mobile;
```

Comment: Why blame the function? Have you tried enabling error_reporting? Do you know what the function is for? (→not HTML output!)

Comment: Is there a connection  to sql server?

Comment: Mysql extension deprecated, no longer available from Php 7.. what's your php version

Comment: Define "not working". Does it format your server drive or something?

Comment: Please add more detail, say what is the output, what does 'not working' means.

Comment: I am using Php 5.6..there is no db connection because i am calling API to store data..

Comment: @AjithamolA Don't use mysql(i)_real_escape_string() for that (anymore), use prepared statements instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try with DB connection ...

Else
Try  mysqli_real_escape_string and mysqli Db Connection

```
mysqli_real_escape_string
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$email=mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_GET['email']);
```

Comment: Please provide some context for your answer.